# Why don't we use parenthesis () when calling the Array.length method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

when we use the length method for strings we use parenthesis, like:

```
String message = "Hello World";
System.out.println(message.length());
```

but when we use the same method with Arrays we don't use parenthesis

```
int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println(numbers.length);
```

We use parenthesis with all other methods but not this one, why is that?

Comment: Because it is not a method. `length` is a field of the array class.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a method. It is a member variable. It can be accessed like this since it is public and final. Since it's final it can't be changed and thus invalidate the array.
This goes back to the early beginnings of java.

Comment: It can be done like this because its final -No, because its public

Comment: @Kris Of course it needs to be public - and it can be exposed as public without risk of anyone trying to change it, since it's final.

Comment: @user16320675  Answer is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

> Why don't we use parenthesis () when calling the Array.length method in Java?

The reason is simple. It is **not a method**, it is just a **public field**.

---

### Example

Pretty much as if you would write a class like this:

```java
public class MyArray {
    public final int length;

    ...
}
```

and then something like

```java
MyArray array = ...
System.out.println(array.length);
```

(this is a contrived example, but you get the idea)

---

### Details

Note that arrays are implemented directly in the JVM and are not just *simple classes* like that. Same holds for `length`.

But those details do not matter much in practice, the syntax the language designers picked is the syntax of a regular `public final int length` field.